# Yii2 - Nginx error with API location but not with ADMIN location

Tags: php, nginx, yii2

I have a problem in my open source web application, im trying create an API application into my web application, but when i access it from browser it never call the "/api/web/index.php" file.

It works:
"http://yii2-app-advanced.local/admin/site/login"

It dont works:
"http://yii2-app-advanced.local/api/customer/login"

I search a lot, make a lot of tests but without success.

This is my nginx file:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/yii2-app-advanced/blob/module-api/extras/docker/nginx/conf.d/yii2-app-advanced.conf

This is the repository:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/yii2-app-advanced/tree/module-api

I put some logs on nginx:

```
URI: /api/customer/login
BOOTSTRAP: index.php
TRY: /api/web/index.php
DOC ROOT: /usr/share/nginx/html/api/web
ROOT PATH: /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Everything appear be correct, because the admin works well and follow the same data changing only api to backend folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add here your routes file, or your routes configuration?

Comment: Stackoverflow dont put everything here because is too long.   

This is my nginx file:   


https://github.com/prsolucoes/yii2-app-advanced/blob/module-api/extras/docker/nginx/conf.d/yii2-app-advanced.conf

Comment: @mrateb I dont have routes in Yii2, they are empty. Nginx send to application and they decide where to go.

Comment: Hi, The problem is not solved. I dont know why the location "/api" dont call "/api/web/index.php", but instead on stop on it, i rename folder to "ws", and now "/api" call "/ws/web/index.php". I dont know if is a bug/problem with "alias" or "try" nginx commands.

If anyone understand about it, please, help me, because my intention is use folder name "api".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    charset      utf-8;
    client_max_body_size  200M;
    listen       80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen       [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    server_name  site.com;
    root         /var/www/site.com;


    location / {
        root  /var/www/site.com/frontend/web;
        try_files  $uri /frontend/web/index.php?$args;
        # avoiding processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
            access_log  off;
            expires  360d;
            try_files  $uri =404;
        }
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/site.com/api/web;
        try_files  $uri /api/web/index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
          access_log  off;
          expires  360d;
          try_files  $uri =404;
        }
    }

    location /admin {
        alias  /var/www/site.com/backend/web;
        rewrite  ^(/admin)/$ $1 permanent;
        try_files  $uri /backend/web/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ^~ /uploads {
       autoindex on;
    }

    # avoiding processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii

    location ~ ^/admin/(.+\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar))$ {
        access_log  off;
        expires  360d;
        rewrite  ^/admin/(.+)$ /backend/web/$1 break;
        rewrite  ^/admin/(.+)/(.+)$ /backend/web/$1/$2 break;
        try_files  $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include  fastcgi_params;
        # check your /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to see if PHP-FPM is listening on a socket or port
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; ## listen for socket
        #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000; ## listen for port
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files  $uri =404;
    }

    #error_page  404 /404.html;

    location = /requirements.php {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ \.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.